# Generate hash code based on object identity in .net

Tags: .net, hashcode

How can I generate a hash code for an object based on its identity.

What I mean is that:

- if `object.ReferenceEquals(a, b) == true`, then `a` and `b` will get the same hash code.
- if `object.ReferenceEquals(a, b) == false`, then `a` and `b` should have a decent chance to get different hash codes even if they are memberwise equal.

What I have is:

```
class SomeClassThatMakesSenseToCompareByReferenceAndByValue {
    override Equals(object o) {
        return MemberwiseEquals(o);
    }

    override GetHashCode() {
        return MemberwiseGetHashCode();
    }
}

class SomeClassThatNeedsReferenceComparison {
    SomeClassThatMakesSenseToCompareByReferenceAndByValue obj;

    override Equals(object o) {
        return o is SomeClassThatNeedsReferenceComparison && object.ReferenceEquals(this.obj, (o as SomeClassThatNeedsReferenceComparison).obj);
    }

    override GetHashCode() {
        return ?????
    }
}
```

Comment: It may help to explain in a bit more detail your use cases for this.

Comment: *"[...] get different hash codes even if they are memberwise equal"* - that sounds a bit odd. Consider the following text from the `GetHashCode` documentation (under "Notes to implementers"): *"If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must return the same value"*. I may miss something though.

Comment: That's why my `SomeClassThatMakesSenseToCompareByReferenceAndByValue` class returns a consistent hash code. But in my other class, I want to use `GetHashCode` AND `Equals` based on identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.gethashcode.aspx)

Comment: it is complete equivalent for object.GetHashCode

Comment: @Andrey it is equivalent only if the dynamic type of object does not override GetHashCode. @erikkallen you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't override `GetHashCode` it will return that *identic* hash code.

Comment: Yes, but I need access to that functionality in another way.

Comment: @erikkallen In what other way?

Comment: given that `object.ReferenceEquals(a, b) == true` I would say that hardly *any* implementation of `GetHashCode` would yield a different result for `a` and `b` (it would basically require involving random elements or time).

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk that's true. i wanted to point to that default implementation will return different hash codes for memberwise equal objects.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do anything - since both objects point to the same instance the same HashCode will always be generated for both objects using the default implementation.